# Memcached Invalid User

Tags: php, memcached

I have a server running CentOs.

I used the guide from http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-memcached-on-centos-fedora-red-hat/ to install it. It says it's installed and everything, but when I type in

```
# /etc/init.d/memcached start
```

I get the error:

```
Starting memcached: chown: 'memcached\r': Invalid User
   to switch toe user memcached
```

I have googled everywhere and can't find an answer.

Anyone have some advice?

Thank you!

Comment: `user memached`? missing a `c` in the username?

Comment: Yes, I missed that letter. Sorry, I was typing it out (I don't know how to copy code from  ssh).  I updated it now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the memcached user is not available on the system, to confirm you can run:

```
$ -> id memcached
uid=497(memcached) gid=497(memcached) groups=497(memcached)
```

If you don't see a similar reponse, then you need to add the user/group:

```
$ -> groupadd memcached
$ -> useradd -g memcached -d /dev/null -s /sbin/nologin
```

Now you should see a response similar to:

```
$ -> id memcached
uid=497(memcached) gid=497(memcached) groups=497(memcached)
```

Comment: I ran "id memcached" and it spit out "uid=104(memcached)  gid=105(memcached) groups=105(memcached)". I didn't have to do the second step. So what would I do now? Does it matter that the first uid=104 and gid=105 and groups=105? All of yours are the same number.

Comment: nah numbers don't mean anything (in this context). Can you start the service now?

Comment: No, same error. The group was already there, so nothing was changed.

Comment: Are you starting the process with elevated privileges? Try `sudo /etc/init.d/memcached start`

Comment: I just tried that and it had the same error for failing. I'm logged in as root too, in case that matters.

Comment: Hmmm the `\r` in the string `Starting memcached: chown: 'memcached\r': Invalid User` is suspect, try editing the memcached script and removing the \r after the chown command.

Comment: I'm a bit new to all this. Where would I edit the script? Like, is it saved in a certain folder?

Comment: here is a link to my /etc/init.d/memcache file. Can you spot any errors? http://104.154.75.2/test.php

Comment: No, it looks fine. Try manually setting the perms on `/var/run/memcached/` directory, so it's owned by the memcached user: `sudo chown memcached /var/run/memcached`